# Making a Game in Unity for android with an offline mySQL database

Tags: c#, php, android, database, unity-game-engine

Im making a trivia and at the end has 5 inputfields for the user data such as name, last name, phone, document number and email. and did a database  with mySQL and phpmyadmin to store this data. when i build for windows everything works fine but i have to build for a android tablet, but i cant manage to get the data base working, i would be glad if anyone can help me!

This is my C# unity script for database management:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class GestorBD : MonoBehaviour
{

public InputField txtnombre;
public InputField txtapellido;
public InputField txtci;
public InputField txttel;
public InputField txtmail;

public string nombrenombre;
public string apellidoapellido;
public int cici;
public int tel;
public string mail;

public bool sesionIniciada = false;

/// Respuestas WEB
/// 
/// 200 = datos encontrados 
/// 201 = usuario registrado
/// 
/// 400 = no pudo establecer coneccion
/// 401 = no enconto datos
/// 402 = el usuario ya existe



public void IniciarSesion()
{
    StartCoroutine(Login());
    StartCoroutine(datos());
}
public void Registrarnombre()
{
    StartCoroutine(Registrar());
}

IEnumerator Login()
{
    WWW coneccion = new WWW("http://127.0.0.1/trivia/login.php?nom=" + 
txtnombre.text + "&ape=" + txtapellido.text + "&ci=" + txtci.text + "&tel=" 
+ txttel.text + "&mai=" + txtmail);
    yield return (coneccion);
    if (coneccion.text == "200")
    {
        print("el usuario si existe");
    }
    else if (coneccion.text == "401")
    {
        print("usuario o contrasena incorrectos");
    }
    else
    {
        print("error en la coneccion con la base de datos");
    }
}

IEnumerator datos()
{
    WWW coneccion = new WWW("http://127.0.0.1/trivia/datos.php?nom=" + 
txtnombre.text + "&ape=" + txtapellido.text + "&ci=" + txtci.text + "&tel=" 
+ txttel.text + "&mai=" + txtmail);
    yield return (coneccion);
    if (coneccion.text == "401")
    {
        print("usuario o contrasena incorrectos");
    }
    else
    {
        string[] nDatos = coneccion.text.Split('^');
        if (nDatos.Length != 2)
        {
            print("error en la coneccion");
        }
        else
        {
            nombrenombre = nDatos[0];
            apellidoapellido = nDatos[1];
            cici = int.Parse(nDatos[2]);
            tel = int.Parse(nDatos[3]);
            mail = nDatos[4];
            sesionIniciada = true;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator Registrar()
{
    WWW coneccion = new WWW("http://127.0.0.1/trivia/registro.php?nom=" + 
txtnombre.text + "&ape=" + txtapellido.text + "&ci=" + txtci.text + "&tel=" 
+ txttel.text + "&mai=" + txtmail.text);
    yield return (coneccion);
    if (coneccion.text == "402")
        Debug.LogError("usuario ya existe!");

    else if (coneccion.text == "201")
    {
        nombrenombre = txtnombre.text;
        apellidoapellido = txtapellido.text;
        sesionIniciada = true;

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("error en la coneccion con la base de datos");
    }

  }


}
```

And this is my php file for login:

```
<?php

$servidor  = 'localhost';
$user      = 'root';
$password  = '';
$baseDatos = 'trivia';

$conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $user, $password, $baseDatos);

$nom      = $_GET['nom'];
$ape      = $_GET['ape'];
$ci       = $_GET['ci'];
$tel      = $_GET['tel'];
$mai     = $_GET['mai'];

if (!$conexion)
{
     echo "error";
}
else
{
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE '$nom' AND apellido 
    LIKE '$ape' AND ci LIKE '$ci' AND tel LIKE '$tel' AND mail LIKE '$mai'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0)
    {
      echo "bien";
    }
    else
    {

      echo "mal";
    } 
 }

?>
```

my php file for data:

```
<?php

$servidor  = 'localhost';
$user      = 'root';
$password  = '';
$baseDatos = 'trivia';

$conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $user, $password, $baseDatos);

$nom      = $_GET['nom'];

if (!$conexion)
{
    echo "400";
}
else
{
     $sql  = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE '$nom'";
     $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
     if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0)
     {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        echo 

 $row['nombre']."^".$row['apellido']."^".$row['ci']."^".$row['tel']
 ."^".$row['mail'];
      }
    }
    else
    {

      echo "401";
    } 
 }

?>
```

and my php file for register:

```
<?php

$servidor  = 'localhost';
$user      = 'root';
$password  = '';
$baseDatos = 'trivia';

$conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $user, $password, $baseDatos);

$nom      = $_GET['nom'];
$ape      = $_GET['ape'];
$ci       = $_GET['ci'];
$tel      = $_GET['tel'];
$mai      = $_GET['mai'];

if (!$conexion)
{
     echo "400";
}
else
{
     $sql  = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ci LIKE '$ci'";

     $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
     if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0)
     {
       echo "402";
     }
     else
     {
       $sql  = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id, nombre, apellido, ci, tel, mail) 
VALUES (NULL, '$nom', '$ape', '$ci', '$tel', '$mai')";
       $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
       echo "201";
     } 
  }

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: i forgot to add that the database have to be offline, as a localhost.

Comment: So, does the problem exist any longer?

Comment: no a error in the game, but the database dont store the information and cant find the problem

Comment: yes the problem is that i cant store the data in the database from the tablet

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a local address (the same machine as the game is running on). If you play the game on your tablet and try to send data to 127.0.0.1, then you're trying to send it to _that tablet_. I'm guessing that you don't have a web server and mysql server on your tablet?

Comment: im using AndroPHP as local server and in that app it display two direcctions one is : http//192.168.0.103:8080 and the other is http//192.168.0.103:8080/phpmyadmin. also i instale phpmyadmin in the tablet, but i will try that ip, so i should replace that ip in the c# script and in the php scripts as well right?

Comment: I just try to use the 127.0.0.1 ip but nothing is not working

Comment: I also put all the php files in a folder named trivia inside of the WWW folder    as i did in my pc

Comment: I just got it working! :)

Comment: If any one is interes, i just replace the ip 127.0.0.1 with the given ip of my androphp app (192.168.0.103:8080) in all of the scripts and is working! Thanks Magnus Eriksson!

Answer (score 0):

Localhost will not work in android as there's no local server set in it like your pc. If you want to store in local database, you'll need to use something like sqlite(https://www.sqlite.org). There's also free asset in assetstore for sqlite: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/20660

For remote server, using the actual server credentials will make it work.